# Django rest framework bind decimal values from Brazilian currency format

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have to serialize data for a django rest framework application, some of values will be on Brazilian currency format like **1.234,45**.

How can I bind those number to work with django rest serializer and django models

My model:

```
class Produto(models.Model):

    prod_codigo = models.AutoField(db_column='prod_codigo', primary_key=True)
    prod_alias = models.CharField(db_column='prod_alias', max_length=50, null=False)
    prod_descricao = models.CharField(db_column='prod_descricao', max_length=255, null=False)
    prod_valor_venda = models.DecimalField(db_column='prod_valor_venda', max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_valor_compra = models.DecimalField(db_column='prod_valor_compra', max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_peso_b = models.DecimalField(db_column='prod_peso_b', max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_peso_l = models.DecimalField(db_column='prod_peso_l', max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
```

My serializer:

```
class ProdutoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    prod_codigo = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    prod_alias = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    prod_descricao = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True)
    prod_valor_venda = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_valor_compra = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_peso_b = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)
    prod_peso_l = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Produto

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Produto.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.prod_codigo = validated_data.get('prod_codigo', instance.prod_codigo)
        instance.prod_alias = validated_data.get('prod_alias', instance.prod_alias)
        instance.prod_descricao = validated_data.get('prod_descricao', instance.prod_descricao)
        instance.prod_valor_venda = validated_data.get('prod_valor_venda', instance.prod_valor_venda)
        instance.prod_valor_compra = validated_data.get('prod_valor_compra', instance.prod_valor_compra)
        instance.prod_peso_b = validated_data.get('prod_peso_b', instance.prod_peso_b)
        instance.prod_peso_l = validated_data.get('prod_peso_l', instance.prod_peso_l)
        instance.prod_peso_q = validated_data.get('prod_peso_q', instance.prod_peso_q)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly and 1.234,45 **equals** to 1.23445 why not handle this on the client side? In my opinion this is the best way to handle to handle format issues.

If you still wanna do it in your backend app you can override **to_representation(self, instance)** 
or use SerializerMethodField like the code below:

```
class ProdutuSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    your_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_your_field_name(self, instance):
        """ stringify your field """
        return "some format" % instance.field
```

Hope that it helps!